# arduino gets response 301 when making a HTTPS GET request

Tags: ssl, redirect, https, arduino

I am making a simple arduino app that send a GET request to a HTTPS site. The code I'm using is exactly the same as the code in the MKRGSM library examples (GsmSslWebClient). But for whatever reason I always get the same response when connecting to a HTTPS site: "301 moved permanently". I kind of know what that means, I am aware that you are supposed to just make another request to the location specified in the header. But I don't know what I have to change to be able to address a https site. I'm sorry for my ignorance and I do know that in the example it clearly states that it connects to `http://www.arduino.cc/asciilogo.txt` but why is it then any different than the normal http example?

I would also point out here, that I have tried changing port to 80 and client settings, to work for unprotected http which works just fine. So its just the https that doesn't work.

this is the code:

```
/*
  Web client

 This sketch connects to a website using SSL through a MKR GSM 1400 board. Specifically,
 this example downloads the URL "http://www.arduino.cc/asciilogo.txt" and
 prints it to the Serial monitor.

 Circuit:
 * MKR GSM 1400 board
 * Antenna
 * SIM card with a data plan

 created 8 Mar 2012
 by Tom Igoe
*/

// libraries
#include <MKRGSM.h>

#include "arduino_secrets.h" 
// Please enter your sensitive data in the Secret tab or arduino_secrets.h
// PIN Number
const char PINNUMBER[]     = SECRET_PINNUMBER;
// APN data
const char GPRS_APN[]      = SECRET_GPRS_APN;
const char GPRS_LOGIN[]    = SECRET_GPRS_LOGIN;
const char GPRS_PASSWORD[] = SECRET_GPRS_PASSWORD;

// initialize the library instance
GSMSSLClient client;
GPRS gprs;
GSM gsmAccess;

// URL, path and port (for example: arduino.cc)
char server[] = "arduino.cc";
char path[] = "/asciilogo.txt";
int port = 443; // port 443 is the default for HTTPS

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  Serial.println("Starting Arduino web client.");
  // connection state
  bool connected = false;

  // After starting the modem with GSM.begin()
  // attach the shield to the GPRS network with the APN, login and password
  while (!connected) {
    if ((gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER) == GSM_READY) &&
        (gprs.attachGPRS(GPRS_APN, GPRS_LOGIN, GPRS_PASSWORD) == GPRS_READY)) {
      connected = true;
    } else {
      Serial.println("Not connected");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }

  Serial.println("connecting...");

  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, port)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.print("GET ");
    client.print(path);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.print("Host: ");
    client.println(server);
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } else {
    // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.available() && !client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    for (;;)
      ;
  }
}
```

and this is the output:

```
Starting Arduino web client.
connecting...
connected
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 19 Nov 2020 20:24:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: close
Location: https://www.arduino.cc/asciilogo.txt
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=500; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

disconnecting.
```

It is also possible that I'm just stupid and the answer is clear as day, but if somebody could please tell me exactly what to do, maybe even put an example, that would be greatly appreciated.
I haven't really tried much except changing the setting to see if they work for normal http and some other libraries that worked even worse. Sadly that's all I could find on the internet since I'm not that skilled to be messing with libraries on my own. I am using **arduino mkr gsm 1400**.

Be sure to call me out if I missed to mention any detail that could help solving this issue

Thanks to anybody that can help me in advance.

Comment: What happens when you try char server[] = "www.arduino.cc"; instead of char server[] = "arduino.cc"; ?

Comment: It doesn't work, server parameter is meant to be used without "www"

Comment: Well, the server is rewriting it to include the "www", so it is disagreeing with you.